# OverridePendingTransition is not working strangely

Tags: java, c#, android, animation, xamarin

I'm a beginnner in Xamarin Android programming as well as in Android programming in general. I successfully run the following code with expected effect:

```
//in the context of the main Activity
StartActivity(someIntent);
OverridePendingTransition(Android.Resource.Animation.SlideInLeft, 
                          Android.Resource.Animation.SlideOutRight);
```

Now I would like to create my own animations for sliding from left and sliding out from right using XML declaration. I put my XML files under the *anim* folder with names `slideInLeft.xml` and `slideOutRight.xml` respectively. Here are the files' content:

**slideInLeft.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemes.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:duration="300"
       android:fromXDelta="-100%"
       android:toXDelta="0%">  
</translate>
```

**slideOutRight.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemes.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:duration="350"
       android:fromXDelta="0%"
       android:toXDelta="100%">  
</translate>
```

Now the code is just simply changed to this:

```
//in the context of the main Activity
StartActivity(someIntent);
OverridePendingTransition(Resource.Animation.SlideInLeft, 
                          Resource.Animation.SlideOutRight);
```

But the animation is not working, the new Activity is just shown after a short of delay (looks like being equal the duration of sliding in which is `300ms`).

This is confusing me. I don't know why and how to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your xml files to:

**slideInLeft**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromXDelta="-100%p" android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="350"/>
</set>
```

AND

**slideOutRight**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="100%p"
        android:duration="350"/>
</set>
```

This should work.

Comment: Well maybe you have tried this yourself and be sure it works. However my code should also work ***if*** I correct a very small typo which is ***schemes*** whereas it should be ***schemas***. Anyway thank you for your help, at least I saw that typo from your answer :)

Comment: Great! have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You try to set duration more longer to see the transition :)

**slideInLeft.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <translate android:duration="5000" 
    android:fromXDelta="-100%" 
    android:toXDelta="0%"/>
    <alpha android:duration="5000" 
    android:fromAlpha="0.0" 
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```

**slideOutRight.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <translate android:duration="5000" 
    android:fromXDelta="0%" 
    android:toXDelta="100%"/>
    <alpha android:duration="5000" 
    android:fromAlpha="1.0" 
    android:toAlpha="0.0" />
</set>
```

Comment: Thank you but the duration is not the problem, 500 or even 300 is good enough to see the effect.